# htacces rewriting for url with ? & id's

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url, seo

I have a tough situation, in which I need to rewrite a url with "?" & "id" to a seo-friendly url.

Here is the actual urls
http://www.example.com/services.html?sr=1 
http://www.example.com/services.html?sr=2 
http://www.example.com/services.html?sr=3 
http://www.example.com/services.html?sr=4

I need to change it to something like this.
http://www.example.com/services/car-dealers.html 
http://www.example.com/services/restaurent.html 
http://www.example.com/services/nonprofit.html 
http://www.example.com/services/school.html

My htacces code

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteRule ^services/car-dealers.html services.html?sr=1 [L]
      RewriteRule ^services/restaurent.html services.html?sr=2 [L]
      RewriteRule ^services/nonprofit.html services.html?sr=3 [L]
      RewriteRule ^services/school.html services.html?sr=4 [L]

      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    </IfModule>
```

I'm using WordPress as the CMS. Any possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a solution of achieving this for the case `sr=1`, do the same for other urls

```
 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sr=1$
 RewriteRule ^services\.html$ /services/car-dealers.html [NC,R=301,L]

 RewriteRule ^services/car-dealers services.html?sr=1 [L,NC]
```

to avoid duplication of code over and over for every url you can use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html), first you create a txt file containing the key values pairs like this:

```
car-dealers 1
restaurent 2
nonprofit 3
school 4
1 car-dealers
2 restaurent 
3 nonprofit 
4 school
```

then in your htaccess:

```
 RewriteMap name2id txt:/etc/apache2/name2idmap.txt

 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sr=([0-9]+)$
 RewriteRule ^services\.html$ /services/${name2id:%1} [NC,R=301,L]

 RewriteRule ^services/(.+?)\.html services.html?sr=${name2id:$1} [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^services/car-dealers services.html?sr=1 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^services/restaurent services.html?sr=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^services/nonprofit services.html?sr=3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^services/school services.html?sr=4 [NC]
```

And visit http://www.example.com/services/car-dealers

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it didn't worked for me. 
http://dev.sreejesh.in/test/services.html?sr=1  not redirecting.

Used following htacces code
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^services/sample services.html?sr=1 [NC]
</IfModule>

Comment: Redirecting wasn't in the question. If you look at http://dev.sreejesh.in/test/services/sample , you will see that it works. Just change all your links to the new clean ones :)